# AWS API Gateway Method Response in CloudFormation - Output passthrough: No

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to configure the Integration Response - Output Passthrough as No. I have configure the parameter PassthroughBehavior as NEVER, however it doesn´t change the output as desired.

[image: How it is deployed with my yaml]

[image: Desired configuration]

Here is my method resource (in YAML):

```
  apiresourcemsactualizartrxtransaccionesv1actualizarTransaccionesoptions:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apigateway
      ResourceId: !Ref apiresourcemsactualizartrxtransaccionesv1actualizarTransacciones
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true
      Integration: 
        PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
        Type: MOCK
        IntegrationHttpMethod: OPTIONS
        IntegrationResponses: 
          - 
            StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,PATCH'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      MethodResponses:
        -
          StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
    DependsOn: apiresourcemsactualizartrxtransaccionesv1actualizarTransacciones
```

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: "doesn´t change the output as desired" is not clear. What exactly is happening? What is current output precisely? What is desired output?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is `PassthroughBehavior` [refers to the request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html), not the output.

I think your output passthrough is setting to "Yes" because your response model is empty. If you set up a model/transform, that should change output passthrough to No.